# new(std::nothrow) instead of new and error handling

Tags: c++, new-operator

I'm learning about new and delete and I don't really understand the `nothrow` part in the code below.

I know that `std::nothrow` is to inform the compiler not to throw exception but is there another reason to write `std::nothrow`?

The code I don't completely understanding is:

```
// Is there another reason to write: 
T *p = new(nothrow) T;
// instead of this:
T *p = new T;
```

And how do I deal with errors in both cases?

Comment: Isn't the answer to your question right there in the question?

Comment: The comments in your code seem to indicate you think the two are the same; they aren't.

Comment: What has research turned up for `nothrow`? Seriously, have you considered searching the web?

Comment: You should post the answer in the Answer box instead of as the first paragraph of the Question box ...

Comment: @Brian Hi, I think I expressed my question wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The keyword [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new) will *allocate space*, *create the object* and return a pointer to that new object in the allocated space.

`T *p = new T;` without `nothrow` is best used with *exceptions* for error reporting because if `new` *fails* it throws `std::bad_alloc` or another exception derived from `std::bad_alloc` (*since C++11*) on failure to allocate memory.

Example:

```
T *p;
try {
    p = new T;
}
catch(const std::bad_alloc &e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << '\n';
}
```

If you're not using exceptions for error reporting, then you should use the `nothrow` option.

Otherwise, when or if new fails, it will throw an *exception*. With the `nothrow` option instead, it will return a null pointer and we can then test for the null pointer like this:

```
T *p = new(std::nothrow) T;
if (p == nullptr) {
    std::cout << "new T failed\n";
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the standard for [nothrow](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/nothrow), it claims that:

> std::nothrow is a constant of type std::nothrow_t used to disambiguate the overloads of throwing and non-throwing allocation functions.

So yes, essentially, this is a *flag* for the compiler to know which allocation function to invoke, and that is it's only standardized function.